# Trying to format a string and it is not working! Android/Java

Tags: android

Here is the XML:

```
<string name="feature3_intro">You shot %1$d pounds of meat!</string>
```

Here is the java code:

```
int numPoundsMeat = 123;  
String strMeatFormat = getResources().getString(R.string.feature3_intro);  
String strMeatMsg = String.format(strMeatFormat, numPoundsMeat);
```

All that is appearing is: `You shot %1$d pounds of meat!`

help?

Thanks!

Comment: Try %d? 1$ is not needed here

Comment: can you show the code, of how you are testing the appearance, like are you setting this string to a textView?.

Comment: Yes this string is being set to a textview:

Comment: <TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/feature3_intro"
    />

Comment: Im new to this. Is there something I have to do in addition to all that I have posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the standard Java `String.format`.  Instead, your code should look like:

```
int numPoundsMeat = 123;  
String strMeatMsg = getResources().getString(R.string.feature3_intro, numPoundsMeat);
textView.setText(strMeatMsg);
```

That's an overloaded version of Android's `getString` method that takes a varargs list and does the formatting for you.

Comment: Thanks! In the above post, what is "textView"? its not defined.

Comment: I didn't define it. It's just a made-up thing to let you know that strMeatMsg is formatted and ready to use somewhere, in this case a TextView.  Also, if this answer does solve your problem, you might consider marking it as the Accepted Answer.

Comment: I have this: String str = getResources().getString(R.string._intro, val1, val2); ------ and _intor is like this: hello %1$s, you are %2$s

Answer (score 0):

since you haven't posted any code and i don't find anything wrong int he information you posted. If you are setting the string to a TextView, i guess you are doing

```
textview.setText(strMeatFormat);
```

instead of you should be using

```
textview.setText(strMeatMsg);
```